# Regex Help Decimal

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match the following patterns:

xxxxxx or xxxx.x

So six digits or 4 digits with a decimal and only one digit to the right of the decimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following regex should do what you want:

```
^\d{4}[\d\.]\d$
```

Comment: +1, I like the lack of an or. This is the way Regex is meant to be run.

Comment: Only it doesn't satisfy the requirements

Comment: oops, sure helps if you don't make typos ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
\d{6}|\d{4}\.\d
```

(filling in space because trivial question doesn't require 30 characters to answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\d{4}(\d{2}|\.\d)
```

escape \d to \d if needed

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d{6}|\d{4}\.\d)$
```

6 whole digits, or 4 whole digits with a single decimal.

You cal also modify the quantifier (`{4}` or `{6}`) to match fewer/more numbers.